# I got a review ban that I don't quite understand

Tags: discussion, review

I recently obtained the review privilege on low quality posts and suggested edits. While still learning the ropes, I try to be as careful as possible. Today I found out I can't review any more. The message on my review page suggests I am under a ban because I haven't taken enough time on reviews.

This is my second review ban. The first ban seemed reasonable. There had been a period of several days when my reviews had been a bit cursory, tending to sway to the lenient side, but I learned from that and have been careful with new reviews. This new ban doesn't seem sensible. As I can't access review history pages, I can only see review actions in my activity page. It seems I have reviewed most of the posts, and looking back I see my views are in agreement with the other reviewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the key part of the message:

> **Please take some time to read posts carefully** and decide what action needs to be taken when reviewing. If you don't want to take the time, please don't review; it causes more harm than good.

This is your second review ban, and in this case it was based on your reviews in the Late Answers and First Posts queues.  In the last thirty days, your average review duration in the Late Answers queue was **only 6.6 seconds**.  We don't feel this is enough time to fully read each post, let alone seriously consider whether action is needed and what action to take.

Consider for example [this review](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/72894).  This post was really more of an extended comment.  It doesn't actually answer the question itself, which is why a moderator later converted it to a comment.  The review history shows that you chose "No Action Needed".

Although none of the reviews are especially egregious individually (you didn't, for example, approve a spam post), we'd really like for you to take the time to read posts fully and consider your reviews a bit more carefully before choosing what to do.

Comment: I take your point, and I will be spending more time on each review. However, I know one thing. After the first ban, I have been more careful than before with each and every review, so much so that with those reviews demanding two reviewers I actually come back hours after the review to see if the second reviewer agrees with me. But that also means more caution, which is part of the reason I tend to leave posts at that. In the past, I had to retract two flags because the poster later revised their posts, rendering my flags irrelevant. In my mind, many things still appear to be in the gray area.

Comment: @L.Moneta I'm glad to hear it.  I'll remove the ban now, and I'll be looking forward to your contributions to the community.

Comment: You can use the skip option if you want to let someone else review a particular post. That’s preferable to “no action” because it leaves the post in the review queue instead of marking it as handled.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see after reviewing your latest review activity, your average review in some categories was 8-10 seconds, which is a red flag that you may not be taking as much care as is needed. Looking at some of the "late answer" reviews it appears that you approved some late answers that had serious quality issues.

It's important to take all reviews seriously, so if you're going to rush through them, we would rather not have you do them at all. We look over the review statistics when we start seeing low quality or spam "late answers" making it through the review queue with no flags. When we see **average** times of under 15 seconds or so along with questionable content approvals, we put a review ban on the account.

You can use the skip option if you want to let someone else review a particular post. That’s preferable to “no action” because it leaves the post in the review queue instead of marking it as handled.